# Text inside a flex box is wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0fs4wxt/)

I have two parent boxes positioned next to each other with flex box, inside of them I have another flex box so the `h2` and `p` can sit side by side.

I've not set a width of the parent boxes and ideally I do not want to.

Why is my text content wrapping when there is space for each flex box to expand? In the example the title is wrapping after `Is` - why can't the `h2` expand so `This Is Title A` appears all on one line?

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

h2 {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

p {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h2>This Is Title A</h2>
    <p>Content.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>This Is Title B</h2>
    <p>Content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it easier for people to see the code in action, for others to copy your code to an answer, and so that others don't have to visit another site.

Comment: use width instead of flex-basis, it's a known issue (finding the duplicate  ...)

Comment: I've tried width instead - the issue is still there.

Comment: You're restricting it by putting width on flex-items i.e `<h2>` and `<p>` using `flex-basis`....that's why

Comment: i removed the flex basis and added the width, does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that percentage lengths use the parent container for reference, and that's missing in your code. The parent of the `h2` and `p` items don't have a defined width.

Once you define a width on the parent (which I know you don't want to do), the problem is resolved. Otherwise, use another unit of length, `white-space: nowrap`, or some other compromise.

> [10.2 Content width: the `width`
>   property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> ***`<percentage>`***
>
> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing
>   block. If the containing block's width depends on this element's
>   width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.2 (and 2.1).

Answer (score -1):

Add flex-grow: 1 and a flex-shrink: 0 to your h2. This will prevent the h2 of shrinking. Also, since you are limiting the relative maximum the h2 can grow (40%) it would break anyway.

EDIT:

flex-grow/shrink was missing in the `.container>div`. Add the rule flex: 1 1 auto; so they expand evenly to fill all the width.

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

h2 {
  flex: 1 0 40%;
  white-space: nowrap:
  /*flex-basis: 40%;*/
}

p {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h2>This Is Title A</h2>
    <p>Content.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>This Is Title B</h2>
    <p>Content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this expands the title to more that 40%. It should be 40 / 60 split with content.

Comment: Still not right with the edit, now the parent boxes are both 50% the width of the screen, they should be their natural width.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not understand the question right. Are you trying to keep the headline in one line no matter what?

Comment: Yes I want the headline on one line, without setting a width on the parent (or any sort of flex growth).

Comment: Try adding ` white-space: nowrap;` to the headline. I just updated the example in my answer.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; does not work either, it does not respect the width 40%.